# How to create a project in IntelliJ then make a GitHub repository for it?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I created a java project in IntelliJ and cannot commit it to the GitHub repo.

I tried creating a repo first on GitHub and creating a project locally but cannot commit it to my repo. It always says the following error.

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I must have done something wrong and can someone give me a clear tutorial on this?

***I want to create a project locally on IntelliJ and then create a git repository for it. NOT the other way around.***

Comment: Hi Roy, 
Go to Search everywhere (double shift)
Type: Share project on
Github will pop up and then you will able to define repo name etc

Btw, did you login to github via ide? This has to be done on: File | Settings | Version Control | GitHub

Comment: That was the issue, after i logged into github everything was solved....it was so simple.